# HTML email center on mobile styles not working on div

Tags: html, css, html-email, responsive

I'm working on a responsive email template and can't get some divs to center on mobile as they should.

I have media queries included in the CSS to center the content on mobile, but they are being ignored on the second div. Not sure if I have the media query styles in the right places in the code. Media queries and div code included for reference.

```css
/*Responsive screens*/
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.stack-column, .stack-column-center { display: block !important;width: 100% !important;max-width: 100% !important;direction: ltr !important; padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important; padding-bottom:0px !important } /*Forces table cells into full-width rows*/
.stack-column-center { text-align: center !important; padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important; } /* And center justify these ones. */
.center-on-narrow { text-align: center !important;display: block !important;margin-left: auto !important;margin-right: auto !important;float: none !important; } /*Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables*/
table.center-on-narrow { display: inline-block !important; }
.email-container p { font-size: 17px !important; } /*Adjusts typography on small screens to improve readability*/
.middle-article-mobile-pt { padding-top: 60px !important; }
.middle-article-mobile-pb { padding-bottom: 60px !important; }
}
```

```html
  <tr>
   <td dir="ltr" height="100%" style="padding: 30px 50px; background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top" width="100%"><!--[if mso]>
                        <table align="center" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                        <![endif]-->
   <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width:500px; padding:0; margin:0;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
     <tr style="padding:0;margin:0;">
      <td align="center" style="font-size:0; padding: 0;" valign="top" class=""><!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="200" style="width: 200px;">
                                    <![endif]-->
      <div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td dir="ltr" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;" class=""><img alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" height="" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/190862/2019-04-09/h9rldk/190862/77786/template_testing_200px_placeholder.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;" width="200"></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" width="300" style="width: 300px;">
                                    <![endif]-->

      <div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; max-width:300px; vertical-align:top;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="center-on-narrow" dir="ltr" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 0 0 20px; text-align: left;">
         <p class="body-h1" style="margin:0;">Headline</p>

         <p class="body-h2" style="margin:0;"><a href="##" style="text-decoration:underline;">Author, CPA<br>
         Title title title title</a></p>

         <p class="body-copy" style="margin: 15px 0;">Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
         <!-- Button : BEGIN -->

         <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="left" bgcolor="#05090c7" pardot-data="" style="border-radius: 2px; background: rgb(255,255,255);" class=""><a class="light-blue-button" href="##"><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]-->Read the Article <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]--></a></td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Button : END --></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--></td>
  </tr>
```

Was expecting the `.center-on-narrow` and `.stack-column` CSS styles to center the div content on narrow but it's being ignored on the second div.

Comment: I tested your code and it works just fine. It centers in mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out! Added some more mobile styles and tweaked the code around the CTA button.

```
        /*Responsive screens*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .stack-column, .stack-column-center { display: block !important;width: 100% !important;max-width: 100% !important;direction: ltr !important; padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important; padding-bottom:0px !important } 
            .stack-column-center { text-align: center !important; padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important; }
            .center-on-narrow { text-align: center !important;display: block !important;margin-left: auto !important;margin-right: auto !important;float: none !important; }
            table.center-on-narrow { display: inline-block !important; }
            .email-container p { font-size: 17px !important; }
            .middle-article-mobile-pt { padding-top: 60px !important; }
            .middle-article-mobile-pb { padding-bottom: 60px !important; }
            .text-right-mobile { padding: 0px !important; }
            .body-copy, .body-copy-2, .body-h1, .body-h2, .light-blue-button, .orange-button, .mobile-center { text-align:center !important; }
        }
```

```
        <tr>
            <td dir="ltr" height="100%" style="padding: 30px 50px; background-color: #ffffff;" valign="top" width="100%" ><!--[if mso]>
                        <table align="center" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                        <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width:500px; padding:0; margin:0;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;margin:0;">
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:0; padding: 0 0 60px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;" valign="top" class=""><!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500" style="width: 500;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="200" style="width: 200px;">
                                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td dir="ltr" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;" class=""><img alt="alt_text" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" height="" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/190862/2019-04-09/h9rldk/190862/77786/template_testing_200px_placeholder.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;" width="200"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" width="300" style="width: 300px;">
                                    <![endif]-->

                        <div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; max-width:300px; vertical-align:top;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="center-on-narrow text-right-mobile" dir="ltr" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 0 0 20px; text-align: left;">
                                    <p class="body-h1" style="margin:0;">Headline</p>

                                    <p class="body-h2" style="margin:0;"><a href="##" style="text-decoration:underline;">Author, CPA<br>
                                    Title title title title</a></p>

                                    <p class="body-copy" style="margin: 15px 0;">Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                                    <!-- Button : BEGIN -->

                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td bgcolor="#05090c7" pardot-data="" style="border-radius: 2px; background: rgb(255,255,255);" class=""><a class="light-blue-button" href="##"><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]-->Read the Article <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]--></a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- Button : END --></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using center tags. This will center the content enclosed by the tags. For an example visit [Center Tags Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp).

Comment: I only want the div to be centered on mobile view, but be left aligned on desktop or tablet. Is there a way I can use the center tags as part of the media query?